# Clicking on anchor takes me to the bottom instead of restoring the previous position

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, position, anchor

I am kind of really stuck with this problem. Any help will great.

I am clicking on a link which expand the content and when i am cliking on a hide button, instead of taking me to the Expand link, it takes me to the bottom.I have already tried such options like onclick="fun() return false" and href=javascrpit:void(0), but not could help.

PLease refer http://jsfiddle.net/BdsyJ/ this link and click on "How do I maximize battery life"  and at the bottom you will get a hide button which should take the control back to the Click it rather than placing the page at the bottom.

Thank you guys.

Comment: you do realize that none of the paths to your css and images are right, right?

Comment: I don't see "Click it---" anywhere in that jsfiddle.

Comment: I am very sorry, please refer to the top second link, "How do I maximize battery life?" THANKS

Comment: @HUNTER, actually i copied the code from my jsp and i missed to remove the css paths. so that is the reason they are seeing different there.

Comment: are you using jQuery? I see `jquery.tools.full.js` so I assume so. I only ask because this might be turbo easy with jQuery

Comment: I tried jquery also, but it dint help, Can you please elaborate more on what do i implelement here with jQuery. I simply called a function onClick and hide the div with $('basic2').hide but it wasnt worked

Comment: check out my updated answer using jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your `ReverseDisplay()` method to this and it works nicely:

```
        function ReverseDisplay(d) {            
            $("#" + d).toggle();

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#" + d).prev().offset().top
            }, 100);          
        }
```

here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/BdsyJ/5/

---

In case you were wondering; **YES** your HTML is invalid. `<li>` elements should not have `<div>` siblings.

Comment: nice! I'd still cache the look up var el = $("#" + d);

Comment: actually i have 2 scrollbars for an example pls refer - http://imgur.com/7Gn64..in that case only outer window goes to the top,but still the inner window comes to at the bottom. Any suggestions pls..

Answer (score 1):

You're at the bottom of the page because you have hidden so much content. Two things I would update in your code:

1. cache the element look up so you only do it once and and
2. scroll the page to the top after you close it using `scrollTo(0,0)` or
   something more complex if you need to scroll back to the exact
   element you toggled.

Code:

```
function ReverseDisplay(d) {
  var el = document.getElementById(d);
  el.style.display = (el.style.display == "none")?"block":"none";
}
```

Comment: pls refer to the http://imgur.com/7Gn64 , where i ve 2 scrollbars ,so how to control the inner window as well?